# Single particle transition rates

Tags: quantum-field-theory

When discussing the cluster decomposition principle in Vol 1 of his QFT textbooks, Weinberg defines $S_{q'q}^C$ (connected part of the $S$-matrix) for single-particle transitions to just be $S_{q'q}$, which then says is equal to $\delta(q'-q)$. Here $q$ labels quantum numbers, so for example $\delta(q'-q)=\delta^3(\mathbf{p}'-\mathbf{p})\delta_{\sigma'\sigma}$ where $\mathbf{p}$ is momentum and $\sigma$ is spin along $z$ direction (in the particle's rest frame).

Why is this true? $S_{q'q}=\delta(q'-q)$ is clearly the case for a non-interacting field theory, but I can't see how it holds in interacting theories. In particular, we have the expression
\begin{align}
S_{\beta\alpha} = \delta(\beta-\alpha) -2\pi i \delta(E_\beta-E_\alpha) T_{\beta\alpha}^+
\end{align}
where to first order in perturbation theory for an interaction $V$, $T_{\beta\alpha}^+=<\Phi_\beta|V\Phi_{\alpha}>$. I don't see why this contribution is zero when $V$ is nonzero.

Edit: He does say later that "we are here assuming that single-particle states are stable, so that there are no transitions between single-particle states and any others, such as the vacuum". Would this amount to imposing $T_{q'q}^+$ by hand? And why does this make sense?

Comment: Tha fact that a state $x$ is stable implies that $S_{x,y} = \delta_{x, y}$ for any state $y$. So the claim that $S^C= 0$ just follows from your quote on your edit.

Comment: Right, but my question is more about why this is a reasonable condition to impose (like, what would lead us to believe that the expectation value of V for single-particle states is zero?). (Also, I'm not sure what you mean by $S^C$ being zero.)

Comment: yes sorry iI meant $S^C = \delta$. Maybe you can reformulate your question on this hypothesis, it is not clear at the moment.